# How use array of datasources?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

I have array of datasource, and I would like bind by data-bind attribute

```
 <div data-role="listview"
         data-template="template3"
         data-bind="source: products"></div>
```

template3:

```
 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template3">
        # for (var y = 0; y < data.length; y++) { #
        <div data-role="listview"
             data-template="template"
             data-bind="source: data[y]"></div>
          # } #

    </script>
```

viewmodel:

```
 var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            products: [new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id"
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("Products", "Home")",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                }
            })]
```

And I get error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Why is there an array around your DataSource?

Anyway, the concrete error you're getting is because `y` is not defined in the context you're trying to access it.

You need to change your template:

```
   # for (var y = 0; y < data.length; y++) { #
    <div data-role="listview"
         data-template="template"
         data-bind="source: data.at(#=y#)"></div>
   # } #
```

Comment: The error disapear, but a datasource don't work. I will have a few datasources. data[0] is undefiend

Comment: yes, but don't understand what is it. " function (e){var n=this;return e===t?n._data:(n._data=this._observe(e),n._pristineData=e.slice(0),n._ranges=[],n._addRange(n._data),n._total=n._data.length,n._pristineTotal=n._total,n._process(n._data),t)}"

Comment: uh, I think I need a demo, sry

Comment: I trying make create sample, but it haven't issue http://jsfiddle.net/dude_jsfiddle/tg404sbo/2/